# Get immediate less value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Here is a [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b70d/18)

In the above fiddle, I will pass a date in where condition and i need immediate less value from the table for each row id.

ie. for example I passed `2012-DEC-09` it need to return
 two rows they are

```
DEL December, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000
MST December, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

I need it in linq query for entity framework.
Cab yiu help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var results = 
    from r in TblDates
    where r.Date < givenDate
    orderby r.Date descending
    group r by r.RoomID into g
    select new {
        g.Key,
        g.First().Date
    };
```

Or perhaps

```
var results = 
    from r in TblDates
    where r.Date < givenDate
    group r by r.RoomID into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).First();
```